How much missing data is too much (part 2)? statistical power, effective sample size
A question is how many missing values are too many to be handled. It has been asked in the context of applying specific software and method (MICE).
I am interested in understanding a bit better what is the fundamental question: Is it appropriate to recast the question of what is too much missingness as what will be the statistical power to estimating a parameter, the sample size, or the degrees of freedom for a method with k parameters?
An answer to the previous SE question links to Harrell stating that "It is useful to look at examples of effective sample sizes in the presence of missing data". The effective sample size is something like the size of a random sample that results in a given variance/precision. So determining what is too much missingness comes down to determining what data size produces a parameter estimate with a given precision.
Now, I also came across King writing in a recent syllabus: "unsolvable problems (such as impossible identification issues, 85% missing data...". So it seems that datasets with less than ~1/5 values being observed aren't effective. But is this because power/n is too weak/small for (a) imputation methods like MICE and Amelia (b) a method of interest for substantive reasons like OLS - to be determinate i.e. to compute?
EDIT: do we need to qualify how data is missing to answer the question e.g. scattered missing values throughout datasets vs. unit non-response where all columns lack observed values?

There is no discrete point at which there are too many missing observations. Even one missing observation can reduce efficiency, or cause bias. On the other hand, valid inference may be obtained even from a complete case sample provided certain assumptions are met, and the resulting sample is of adequate sample size. The information recovery using missing data methods warrants consideration, but it is (as with most things) a sliding scale.

Thanks for input, @AdamO. I am not sure I understand your point following "on the other hand..." unless it is simply to say that without missing data there is no problem. Did I understand you correctly? Moreover, if you had to guess, why would you believe King talks about 85% missing data as a threshold?

What is King talks?

@AdamO King states in the materials I cited that 85% missing data is unsolvable, which I suppose means that models wont compute or provide valid, useful estimates.

I will put this to an answer.

It really depends on the situation and what is possible. E.g. telephone survey may only have a 5 to 10% response rate. So, for 90 to 95% of people that were called their answers are missing. Obviously, this is a concern and the potential for non-response bias is constantly discussed, but it's incredibly hard to avoid this issue. People then come up with ideas for how to deal with this (e.g. using population distributions to re-weight samples).
In clinical trials, that would be a shocking amount of missing data (for something that's meant to be there for all participants, of course something else if that was never the intention) and everyone would question how data that was meant to be recorded is missing to such an extent.
So, in the end, I don't think there's a simple rule. More extents of missing data that are typical for certain areas and that people have got used to.

Thanks for your reply. It seems to me that you are discussing unit non-response, am I right? Is that fundamentally a similar problem as missing values scattered throughout a dataset?

Another point: Response rates might be 10% and the sample size "large" and hence not conceptualized as a problem of "missing data" but rather unit non-response bias?

Sure there's a special name for it, but the responses from those people are missing. Large amounts of (non-missing) data do not change concerns and biases arising from missing data. The only thing a lot of data helps with is stabilizing things numerically (likely no convergence issues for methods, can estimate well what's going on in those with non-missing data, just need to figure out what this means for the question of interest).

Doesn't that hint in the direction of agreement with King's assertion that missing values above some threshold makes estimating models useless, in other words, that there is a rule of sorts of how much missing data is too much?

FYI I found this discussion of non-response and missingness by one MICE dev https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/ch-selection.html and https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-idconcepts.html

My reading of the syllabus is that King mentioned 85% as a scandalous example, not as a hard threshold. The impact of missing values is a spectrum not a threshold. Quality (in terms of bias and accuracy) degrades the more missing you have.

@ecnmetrician you may be right in that interpretation. But then I just don't understand why he goes so far to call it "unsolvable". That seems hard to me.

I think "unsolvable" might refer to the fact that the computer outputs a number, it's just that the number might be meaningless, and more math (might not) help you make it meaningful, i.e. more math does not replace high quality data. Of course, this statement should also be taken with a grain of salt, since there are many different types of approaches to this type of problem, some which might be well suited to specific instances and some which might not.

Another way to think of "unsolvable" is the data alone cannot reveal the answer: you need to make assumptions to interpret results, based on contextual or historical knowledge, and such assumptions are untestable with the data at hand. "Missing at random" is an example of this type of assumptions - if you I impose it you get meaningful results, but there's no sure way to know if "Missing at random" is true, per se. The important lesson is that when you have missing data you do lose something: the ability to let the results that speak for themselves without auxiliary assumptions.

I think your comments are excellent @ecnmetrician, consider moving them to you answer

Something that hasn't come up yet in the answers: It's not the amount of missing data that matters, it's the amount of missing information. If you ask someone's height in inches, and you also ask their height in centimeter, 90% of your centimeter data can be missing - but that's not much of an issue, because we're not missing much information.
In my work, I might have (say) 500 raters, rating 2000 objects (on a continuous [ish] scale). Each object might only be rated by a randomly selected 5 raters. So in one sense, 99% of my data are missing.
I would like to know what rating an object would have, had every rater rated it. I can take the average of the 5 raters, but this would introduce noise.
I have enough information from each rater to know what their rating profile is like, and enough ratings of each item, that I can estimate what rating I would have got from all 1000 raters. And I can do a reasonable job of that with 99% of my data missing, because I'm not missing much information.
Paper here that discusses more: On Obtaining Estimates of the Fraction of Missing Information From Full Information Maximum Likelihood by Victoria Savalei
& Mijke Rhemtulla.

Interesting that missing information is defined as "the impact of missing data on the quality of estimation of a particular parameter" cf. your source. But I don't understand or perhaps tend to disagree that one can do a reasonable job at estimating a quantity of interest with 99% missing data.

I have potentially a very large number of highly correlated measures. Because these are correlated a random sample gives a pretty good estimate (Spearman-Brown prophecy formula can tell us how good). Each rater also has a consistent bias - by adjusting for that bias (we call that debiasing), we can get a better estimate.
[cont ...]

We evaluate this by giving some objects to rate to 1000s of raters - so we have no missing data, and can calculate the average score. Then we randomly sample some of those measures, run the debiasing, and see how well we predicted the score with all raters.  We get pretty close (and as we increase the number sampled, we get closer - there's virtually nothing to be gained above 30 raters). It's a bit like sampling from a population - a sample of 1000 might be 1% of the population, or 0.1%, but if it's random, it's equally good.

Alright, so that’s in the situation of measuring some latent factor with a proper measurement instrument. But I am not sure FIML works in areas outside psychometry.

I think it's true any time your data that are missing are in a variable that is strongly predicted by other variables. But I only have evidence for my example.

Missing data generates two issues:

It potentially generates sample selection bias.
It reduces your effective sample size. In an i.i.d. setting, the effective sample size is just the number of non-missing observations. If you are using a model with more than one variable, the effective sample size is the number of complete rows.

Why does bias emerge? Suppose that we have $N$ data points that take values $(Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_N)$ that takes values between $[a,b]$. If we observed all $N$ data points, the sample average would be
$$ \bar{Y}_{full} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i $$
Now suppose that you only observe the firs $S$ observations, where  $S\le N$, and that the rest have missing values. Suppose that we could hypothetically compute averages for both the missing and non-missing observations, as follows
$$ \bar{Y}_{non-miss} = \frac{1}{S}\sum_{i = 1}^S Y_i $$
$$ \bar{Y}_{miss} = \frac{1}{N-S}\sum_{i=S+1}^N Y_i.$$
With some algebra we can show that
\begin{align*} \bar{Y}_{non-miss} &= \bar{Y}_{full} + \frac{N-S}{N}( \bar{Y}_{non-miss} - \bar{Y}_{miss}) \\
&= \bar{Y}_{full} + \text{Proportion missing} \times  Bias 
\end{align*}
For example, suppose that $Y_i$ indicates whether you are feeling sick, but you only this for people that go to the hospital. Here $\bar{Y}_{full}$ is the population average of sick people, $\bar{Y}_{non-miss}$ is the proportion of sick individuals in an emergency room, and $\bar{Y}_{miss}$ is the proportion of sick individuals that do NOT go to an emergency room. In this case, it makes sense that $\bar{Y}_{non-missing} > \bar{Y}_{miss}$, and so the bias is positive (the hospital will have more sick people than the average population). Of course, another alternative is to switch the goal: say that you are interested in analyzing the subpopulation of hospital patients rather than the whole population. What's important is understanding these biases.
For your original question you talked approximately (0.85) missing. and so the total distortion is $0.85\times Bias$. There's nothing special about $85\%$ missing, though the formula suggest that generally having more missing observations amplifies the bias.
Conclusion:

The total distortion gets worse when the relative proportion of missing is higher, unless $\bar{Y}_{non-miss} \approx \bar{Y}_{miss}$ (or more formally, the expectations for missing and non-missing observations).  This assumption is known as missing at random and can be generalized to univariate or multivariate, linear and non-linear, with additional notation.
In i.i.d settings, the effective sample size is $S$. Lower sample sizes impact power. If you think that bias is not important for your setting, you can do power calculations with the effective sample size.

Note that there are alternatives to missing at random. For instance, you could construct worst and best case bounds for the missing observations, if your outcomes are bounded in $[a,b]$.

So do you agree with AdamO that a "large" proportion of missing values is not problematic per se?

Yes, if missing values are missing at random, you could still get valid inference.

Except that estimates will be biased toward zero, right?

Yes, with missing at random, there's no bias.

@Johan why biased to zero? No particular reason that would be the case.

the effective sample size is just the number of non-missing observations is not true if the observations are correlated. E.g. if we are interested in the height of an average American and we measure 1 person 100 times instead of measuring each of 100 different persons once, the effective sample size is 1, not 100.

@Björn I’m glad you ask. Let me answer with a question. Isn’t it the case that estimates tend toward zero 1) the more noise there is in the measure/indicator or 2) the fewer observations/rows there are?

Be careful not to confuse measurement error issues with missing value issues. Indeed, in a regression model of $Y = Xb + e$ with $X$ measured with random noise (more specifically, "classical measurement error"), the coefficient is attenuated towards zero. This is completely different from having missing observations. With "missing at random" you tend to the true population quantity. To clarify, my earlier comment meant "zero bias" not "bias towards zero".

@Björn I fixed the wording to clarify that this is for i.i.d settings.

@Johan, no, in a linear regression setting noise is noise and can can go either way (i.e. there's no reason why there would be a systematic bias towards 0). Of course, there are some particular situations where it can. Noise biasing estimates is on average a thing with certain non-linear link functions (e.g. omitting covariates in a logistic regression), but not linear regression. In some very particular setting e.g. observational comparisons of treatment measurement error can introduce bias (while e.g. for baseline covariate adjustment in randomized experiments that is not the case).

@ecnmetrician may I add With "missing at random" you tend to the true population quantity ... as n increases? Such that yes if it is missing 'completely at random' then of course the estimates are valid. But it reduces the power to estimate parameters and hence will increase estimate uncertainty and therefore tend toward zero? Apologies if I am going astray and thank you very much for your engagement - it is highly appreciated.

Yes, as $n$ increases. Perhaps we're getting lost in what you mean by "tend to zero". If the proportion of missing is fixed as you increase $n$, the standard errors still converge to zero with large $n$, but may be slightly larger in size than if you observe the full sample, which is what causes the loss in power. Even though the standard errors themselves go to zero the estimate $\bar{Y}_{non miss}$ can still converge to a non-zero quantity.

You are right, it was a misnomer on my part. Listwise deletion given MCAR does not bias estimates downwards but simply makes the point estimate harder to detect. Indeed as you said, be careful not to confuse measurement error issues with missing value issues.

If imputation is what you care about, then what matters is not only the proportion of missing data, the amount of missing information, and the randomness-of-missingness (MCAR vs MAR vs NMAR), but also the amount of observed data. Consider Scenario A: 100 samples of fully-observed data and 1000 samples with 90% missingness, vs Scenario B: 10 samples of fully-observed data and 100 samples with 90% missingness. Even though the proportions are the same, and even if both are MCAR, the former scenario will allow you to better validate whether your imputation process worked correctly.
How exactly you run your imputation procedure also matters. For example, MICE may "hallucinate" samples if you have a large proportion of missingness and you run it for too many iterations. The reason is that, at the first iteration, MICE fills in missing values randomly, and then trains predictive models on the entire (including imputed) dataset. At each iteration, re-imputes missing values using the predictive models; then MICE refits a predictive model based on imputations. Thus, MICE can be led astray by bad initial random values, because these influence the trained models.
In fact, I would suggest looking at alternatives to MICE, such as UnmaskingTrees. UnmaskingTrees introduces new missing values and then trains predictive models to iteratively impute them; then it applies these models to the actual missing values. Rather than training on its own model outputs as does MICE, UnmaskingTrees creates new (MCAR) missingness to train itself on, and only trains itself on actual data values. For example, see how MICE-Forest and UnmaskingTrees behave on the Two Moons dataset with 60% missingness. UnmaskingTrees is much more conservative, imputing values much closer to the actual fully-observed samples.

Finally, the answer depends on what you want to do with your dataset with missing values. Because you mention MICE, I assume that you are focused on imputing these missing values then performing analysis as if no missing data was present. Note that the answer may be different if you're actually only interested in using the data for some downstream prediction task. Then you may use a method (such as XGBoost) that handles missing features and simply see whether your prediction performance on held-out data meets your desired criteria.

In many ways a great answer. Not least for clearly exemplifying that the proportion of missingness and the absolute amount of data are both important when considering the power to estimate models, imputation models included. I suppose that is why it can be useful to distinguish between e.g. unit non-response bias and Swiss-cheese datasets. ...

And thanks for highlighting your work. That's exciting news to me, and it has my attention. One question: In what sense do you mean that UnmaskingTrees is much more conservative? I tend to presume that more conservative estimates are more spread out around point estimates or with greater uncertainty, rather than more accurate (meaning that point estimates being closer to the true parameter)? Do you mind commenting on this? ...

And thanks for mentioning XGBoost too. I did already look into it. Though the estimators/methods aren't the same, FIML also seems to enable carrying out analysis of substantive interest despite data not being complete. I guess a concern is whether the methods require no missingness in dependent variables though.

Last, are you aware of imputation methods for classification or missing labels?

@Johan By "conservative", I mean that UnmaskingTrees imputed the red dots to be close to the fully-observed orange Xs, whereas MICE-Forest created green dots that are far from any fully-observed samples in the training data.

@Johan The fit method of UnmaskingTrees accepts user input that indicates whether each feature is continuous, categorical, or integer. https://github.com/calvinmccarter/unmasking-trees/blob/da2cf56599527d9345f81b597e37d1c8d80027e1/utrees/unmasking_trees.py#L157 For classification, one can turn the label into a feature, and tell the method that it's categorical.

Interesting stuff! I would not call it conservative but more accurate. As a side note, I was of the belief that MI tries to reflect/maintain a distribution rather than an estimator. Looking forward to trying your tool and following your project!

The proportion of missingness is simply not a problem. Rather there are two issues to consider:

The power and accuracy of the overall proposed analysis
The validity of the missing data assumptions.

As explained in Rubin's Book on Missing Data, we can classify the missing data mechanism. The worst-case scenario is informative missingness or not missing at random (NMAR), this is the scenario that non-response indicates a bias exists. In this case, even <1% missingness indicates a problem, and there's no real omnibus to handle it.
If we can exclude this NMAR scenario, then for most applications any analysis is unbiased and missingness affects the efficiency of power of the target analysis. This missingness scenario is called missing at random or missing completely at random (MAR or MCAR). If you collect 500 observations, and 50% have missing data and conduct a complete case analysis, you discard 250 observations with some missingness and your final power is not structurally different from an analysis of the other 250 observations with complete data. Similarly, 85% missing data means an 85% reduction in power, i.e. an analysis of 75 observations.
The contribution of missing data methods of EM algorithms or MI procedures at this point is that you recover some (but not all) of the power lost to missing data by considering the fraction available in the data that would be discarded in a complete case analysis.

I like this answer. Perhaps it might be more correct to say that the proportion of missingness is not a problem in and of itself but only as far as concerns (or in and of itself but goes through) statistical power and the reason for missingness.

Another contribution or MI methods to the extent they do what they purport to do is to replace misleading practices for handling missing values. Practices that cause bias, including listwise deletion in the sense that less information creates more uncertainty about point estimate sizes (perhaps to the point of not being detectable).

@Johan the converse is a popular view among reviewers, especially as concerns NHST. If, for instance, MI is just enough to cross a significance threshold, they tend to discredit the result as boiling down to statistical trickery.

hm well so it seems reviewers (not only NHST practitioners) are themselves motivated reasoners blaming a method to address a problem (i.e. missing data) due to aversion toward a mode of statistical inference. They might as well dislike developing better measurement instruments that enable more substantial estimates. That’s up-hill and too bad.
